# What is the most up-to-date CRISPR/Cas9 protocol?

Tags: molecular-biology, literature, crispr

I am collecting literature to start a new project on CRISPR/Cas9 gene editing. I must put together a protocol to start and am intending to use the following paper as guidance:

"Genome engineering using the CRISPR-Cas9 system". Nature Protocol 8(11):2281-308 · November 2013

Could you please indicate whether this is the most reliable and recent published general protocol for the CRISPR/Cas9 system.

Comment: A PubMed search will tell you that.

Comment: Dear  MattDMo, I am aware of that. There are many papers to choose from and go through all will take large amounts of time. What I am aiming for is to collect information from experienced people and optimize my time. Thanks

Comment: Sergio - the way to do this is to search pubmed, and sort by date. Alternatively, email somebody from a lab who is currently performing CRISPR and ask them, usually people are happy enough to help with simple questions like that.

Comment: You can easily find out if it is most recent, if it is most reliable is an opinion-based question and as such out of the scope of this platform.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with it. Sticking to genome engineering in Human cells, [Nature Protocol 8(11):2281-308 · November 2013](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v8/n11/full/nprot.2013.143.html) is the de-facto standard. One improvement I suggest is to replace the "Surveyor Assay" with deconvolution analysis of sequencing traces using [TIDE](https://tide.nki.nl).